# Why z-index does not working in ios iphone (6)?

Tags: html, ios, iphone, css

I'm trying to up the menu layer using `z-index`. Its working on `chrome`, `FireFox`, `I.E`, `Safari` and other small screens (`Android Mobiles`). But it doesn't work in iphone 6 safari browser. Following are the my code.

### CSS

```
.main-menu-nav ul.custom-dropdown li {
    z-index: 10000;
    background: #e7058c;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #F97DC7;
}
.nav>li {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
```

### HTML

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav custom-dropdown">
    <li class=""><a href="#">special</a></li>
</ul>
```

I searched about it and find a well explained [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16033416/while-scrolling-on-an-ios-device-the-z-index-of-elements-isnt-working), i tried this but does not working. Can any one guide me how can fix this issue.

Comment: This will help, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16033416/while-scrolling-on-an-ios-device-the-z-index-of-elements-isnt-working

Comment: @DeepanshuMishra I already mentioned in my question, i followed this answer but it it does not working.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `transform: matrix3d();` instead on z-index

Where you can set "X" "Y" "Z" axis of an object.