# Sticky Header in Safari available but not visible (JavaScript Class sticky added)

Tags: javascript, css, browser, safari

I added a sticky Header to my webshop, and it works fine with FF, Chrome, Edge.

In Safari (Windows 10) JavaScript is executed, the header is fixed and transformed - but not visible!

When the Cursor is on the positions of the Menu-Buttons the Tooltips/Link-Titles are showing, also I can use them and click on them.

But its invisible! Because Safari is build by apple I know that´s a feature, not a bug - but it would be very helpful, when the header would be visible to safari-users also!

You can look at it here: https://www.toner-dumping.de - any suggestions?

Comment: well it's 2018 who cares safari for windows ?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
#kopfmenue_responsive {
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [safari bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16033416/while-scrolling-on-an-ios-device-the-z-index-of-elements-isnt-working)

Just Remove `z-index` from `#kopfmenue_responsive.sticky`